# Django filter foreign key by booking dates

Tags: python, django, date

I have the following model:

```
class House(models.Model): 
   Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) 
   Reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Booking(models.Model): 
   House = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='booking')
   InitialDate = models.DateField()
   FinalDate= models.DateField()
```

Now, I want to perform a query to filter all the AVAILABLE houses for a range date (eg: 2013-07-21 to 2013-07-30), so It should exclude all the houses with a booking starting and ending between those two dates.
I would be able to perform this query with raw SQL but no with the django syntax.

Could anyone please help?

Many thanks!

Comment: What raw SQL did you use?

Answer (score 4):

When using the Django ORM one of the practices used is that you should always start with the relationship you want to end up with, in your case `House`.

I argue that this would be your way of going about it then:

```
unbooked_houses = House.objects.exclude(
    booking__InitialDate__gte=start_date, booking_FinalDate__lte=end_date)
```

This way you'll end up with a `QuerySet` and need not bother with list comprehensions and whatnot.

Furthermore, [Python PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) document dictates that you should follow the following naming convention for variables and properties:

Instead of `InitialDate` it should preferably be `initial_date`.

Comment: I didn't because when I post I reedit multiple times often. so if you were editing at the same time, I don't know what would have happend.

Comment: also, your test don't say if the house is booked in a part of the interval. *strange to note that I'm the only one who upvoted this answer* hey miki, you can upvote and accept answers

Answer (score 3):

I took the freedom to use a more pythonic case.

```
class House(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True) 
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Booking(models.Model): 
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, related_name='booking')
    initial_date = models.DateField()
    final_date= models.DateField()

import datetime
start_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 07, 21)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2013, 07, 30)

# so simply intersect
booked = set(values['house_id'] for values in Booking.objects.objects.filter(
    initial_date__lte=end_date, final_date__gte=start_date).values('house_id'))

House.objects.exclude(id__in=booked)
```

thanx to richsilv for the set idea, logical but I thaught about it by reading his answer. It simply reduce the sql statement by only using distinct houses.

Comment: Many thanks to you all! Is working now! Great answers everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the period you're talking about is between `startdate` and `enddate`, would this work:

```
booked = set([x.House.Reference for x in \
   Booking.objects.filter(InitialDate__lte=enddate).filter(FinalDate__gte=startdate)])
available = House.objects.exclude(Reference__in=booked)
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? I don't understand this line: booked = set([x.House.Reference for x in \

Comment: It returns the set (i.e. no repeated entries) of all house references for which there are bookings between the dates in question.  Note that \ is a continuation character, so this line continues with `Booking.objects...`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to directly filter thanks to the reverse relation created by Django :

`bookedHouses = House.objects.filter(booking__InitialDate__lte=enddate)\
.filter(booking__FinalDate__gte=startdate)`